# Close button doesn't work in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, modal-dialog

I've put a modal dialog in my project, that pulls up a partial view.  It works great, but the close button does not work.

I've tried self-referencing it with $('#resetPasswordDialog').dialog('close'); , no dice.  What am I doing wrong?  This seems relatively simple to me, and every example I've read shows that simply calling $(this).dialog("close"); works.

I'm currently using this in MVC2.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content(" jquery-1.6.2.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#resetPasswordDialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 750,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Reset Password',
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load('<%: Url.Action("ResetPassword") %>');
                },
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $('.forgot-password-button').click(function () {
                $('#resetPasswordDialog').dialog('open');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: So what happens in the console window of the javascript debugging tool you are using when you click on this Close button? An error message maybe?

Comment: You will need to put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing your error. Those are some pretty old versions of the libraries, so it could be anything.

Comment: Could you post the ASP.NET code?  Are you sure the buttons have the correct IDs?  What happens if you put in a console.log("testing call") before the $(this).dialog("close");

Comment: @RichardEB, `dialog('close')` and `dialog("close")` has nothing to do with any API. `'close'` and `"close"` are 2 perfectly equivalent ways to represent a string literal in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
 buttons: {
  "Close": function () {
      alert('test');
      $(this).dialog("close");
   },
  Cancel: function() {
     alert('test2');
     $(this).dialog("close");
   }
 },
beforeClose: function() {
  alert('test3');
}
```

Would adding these alert anything in your code?

Comment: Yes, in your first example, adding an "alert('test');" before $(this).dialog("close"); does in fact throw an alert.  it looks like it's hitting the function just fine, but $(this).dialog("close"); does nothing.  Again, I should mention that I've even tried $('#resetPasswordDialog').dialog('close');.

@Brian Hoover (in above comment):  Yes, everything has the correct ID's.  If they did not, the modal dialog wouldn't open, and the partial view within wouldn't work well either.

Comment: Now that I think about it, once the dialog is closed, it cannot be reopened until the page is refreshed.  I think that once the dialog is opened, something is essentially making it impossible to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason for you not beeing able to run the script if because of partial view.

My work around is:
Try to put the javascript for the dialog box into parent page. eg no partial views

hope this help